# Rails 4 Params missing, Rspec testing nested resources controller update method

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller

New to rails here,

I understand the error but I don't get why my test isn't passing.  I also don't know how to look at the params hash that is being passed into the action either, so debugging is kinda confusing for me.

Failing test error

```
1) SectionsController PATCH #update with valid attributes finds the correct course.section assigns @section
     Failure/Error: patch :update, course_id: @section.course_id, id: @section.id
     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: section
     # ./app/controllers/sections_controller.rb:52:in `section_params'
     # ./app/controllers/sections_controller.rb:36:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/sections_controller_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Test

```
describe "PATCH #update" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      before :each do 
          @course = create(:course)
          @section = create(:section, name: "section1")
      end
      it "finds the correct course.section & assigns @section" do 
        patch :update, course_id: @section.course_id, id: @section.id
        expect(assigns(:section)).to eq(@section)
      end
    end
end
```

Section Controller update method

```
def update
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @section = Section.find(params[:id])
      if @section.update_attributes(section_params)
      flash[:success] = "the section has been updated"
      redirect_to [@course, @section]
    else
      flash[:error] = "you must enter the correct information"
      render action: "edit"
    end
  end

private 

  def section_params
    params.require(:section).permit(:name, :course_id) 
  end
end
```

Routes

```
resources :courses do
    resources :sections
end
```

Models

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :course
    validates :name, :course_id, presence: true
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sections
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sections
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: try this to see if it fixes:  `post :update, course_id: @section.course_id, id: @section.id, section: {name: @section.name,course_id: @section.course_id}`

Comment: It worked!  Thank you so much and sorry for the late reply,  I was away all weekend.  So i was missing the attributes for section it looks like?

Comment: Great, I'll post an answer for you to accept then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do a post with all the required parameters is as follows:

```
post :update, course_id: @section.course_id, id: @section.id, section: {name: @section.name,course_id: @section.course_id}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. The question was about using PATCH. POST is for new objects. PATCH is for a delta PUT (update)